# php xdiff_file_diff and xdiff_file_patch functions used for loading new chat messages

Tags: php

It's a chat script that:

1. appends typed text in newfile.txt on form submit with action process.php.
2. Than I have ajax with setInterval checking the difference with xdiff_file_diff() if there is a difference between newfile.txt, and oldfile.txt and write the difference in diff.txt.
3. the script uses xdiff_file_patch() to patch oldfile.txt to eliminate the difference.

The purpose of the script is to .append() with jQuery only new messages into chat div for messages, so the whole chat messages are not reloading because I have youtube videos in iframes so they dont get interrupted, and in general I think this is better approach.

**Question** that i have, is the logic in the code ok, because I see old inputs printed out on chat and how would I go with removing clutter form diff.txt and display only the text difference?

The files i have:

process.php part of file

```
$myfile = fopen('newfile.txt', 'a') or die('unable to open file');
$txt = $_POST['text'] . "\n";
fwrite($myfile, $_SESSION['username'] . ': ' . $txt);
```

loadmessages.php

```
xdiff_file_diff('oldfile.txt', 'newfile.txt', 'diff.txt');
$myfile = fopen('diff.txt', 'r') or die('unable to open file');
if(filesize('diff.txt') > 0)
{
    $text = fread($myfile, filesize('diff.txt'));
    $text = str_replace('\n', '<br />', $text);

    $yt = linkifyYouTubeURLs($text);
    echo '<div class="message">' . filterText($array, $yt) . '</div>';


    xdiff_file_patch('newfile.txt', 'diff.txt', 'oldfile.txt');
    file_put_contents('diff.txt', '');


}
fclose($myfile);
```

ajax

```
function loadmessages2()
        {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'loadmessages.php',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data != '')
                    {
                        $('#chat_bubble').append(data);

                        $(document).on('submit','#frmsend',function(){
                            $("#chat_bubble").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#chat_bubble")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);


                        });


                        $("#chat_bubble").stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#chat_bubble")[0].scrollHeight}, 1000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And the result demo is:

[image]

Comment: Never mind the logic in detail - I would say that using xdiff for such purposes is rather wrong to begin with already. Store the messages with their timestamps, request new messages based on that.

Comment: ok, I will try that approach

Comment: What do you mean by "ok"? If that code solves your problem, it should be fine. If there is any real problem, can you state it more clear? Additionally, are you sure you want to use files for this - wouldn't this cause tons of problems if two people are writing at the same time?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, there are problems, but I will try to look for solution my self first if that is ok because I don't know how this approach works for now. You can help if you want ofcourse